# android webview goes blank in PWA frameworks

Tags: javascript, android, webview, onsen-ui, html-framework-7

i have an app that use webview for interface. i want to use PWA frameworks such as Onsen UI or Framework7. these frameworks working well in local browser but not in webview.
in webview every thing goes blank without any error. i enabled and checked various things on android and webview but nothing worked.
this is my webview settings :

```
    ws.javaScriptEnabled=true
    ws.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically=true
    ws.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
    ws.databaseEnabled=true
    ws.allowContentAccess=true
    ws.allowFileAccess=true
```

and also i checked asset loader but nothing happend.
one thing i should emphasis is that every thing completly loaded in webpage but again it does not work!

EDIT *** : i checked and this address https://onsen.io/demo/ as demo does not open in webview and is blank again. i dont know why!

Answer (score 0):

finally  found the answer!
when we using webview with nestedscrollview the webview's height is set to wrap_content and this cause problem. we must use an absolute height for webview.